# What statistical test to compare frequencies across groups?

Tags: statistics, chi-squared

I am running an analysis in which I want identify if there are significant differences in the features that make up two groups: people that commit crimes against children and people that commit crimes against adults – the group sizes are not equal.

My data is all frequency counts, and has been added up to create percentages

For example –

80% of offenders that commit crimes against children are male 20% are female

75% of offenders that commit crimes against adults are male 25% are female

50% of offenders that commit crimes against children plead guilty, 20% plead not guilty, 30% are acquitted

20% of offenders that commit crimes against adults plead guilty, 60% plead not guilty, 20% are acquitted

I want to know:

Is there a significant difference in the number of females that commit crimes against adults vs. females that commit crimes against children?

Is there a significant difference in the number of males that commit crimes against adults vs. males that commit crimes against children?

Is there significant difference in the number of guilty pleas/ non guilty pleas/ acquittals/ from offenders that commit crimes against children vs. offenders that commit crimes against adults?

Is there significant difference in the number of guilty pleas/non-guilty pleas / acquittals between those commit offences against adults vs. those that commit offences against children?

I am thinking it should be a chi-squared test – but this seems to be for answering questions such as ‘is there a significant difference between the number of men vs. the number of women that commit crimes against children?’ rather than answering ‘is there a significant difference in the number of women that commit crimes against children vs. the number of women that commit crimes against adults?’

Also, in a chi squared test, would my ‘expected value’ just be what I observed in one group and my ‘observed value’ be what I observed in the other group? I,e., I expect the groups to be the same.

I also thought about a t-test where male and female could be coded as 0 and 1 but that would give no standard deviations so would not be feasible.

I would greatly appreciate any help or advice with this or on which test would be appropriate, thank you!